# rauth 0.5.5 failed installation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rauth

generating error as this

```
C:\sankar\rauth-0.5.5.tar\rauth-0.5.5>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rauth import __version__
  File "C:\sankar\rauth-0.5.5.tar\rauth-0.5.5\rauth\__init__.py", line 30, in <m
odule>
    from .service import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service, OflyService
  File "C:\sankar\rauth-0.5.5.tar\rauth-0.5.5\rauth\service.py", line 23
    except KeyError, e:  # pragma: no cover
```

Comment: And the actual exception is?

Comment: File "C:\sankar\rauth-0.5.5.tar\rauth-0.5.5\rauth\service.py", line 23 except KeyError, e: # pragma: no cove

Comment: You forgot to include the exception message line; probably a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

The module won't work on Python 3, as it uses Python 2 specific syntax.

There is an open [pull request for supporting Python 3](https://github.com/litl/rauth/pull/100). You can try to use the patch in that pull request, or switch to Python 2.

Update: As of [version 0.6](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/#changes-in-version-0-6-0) `rauth` supports Python 3. Install that version or newer.

Comment: The [Python 3](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/python-3) branch has been tested with Python 3 and should work.

Comment: The latest version of rauth implements Python 3.3 support.